# CSS doesn't work properly with HTML tag a

Tags: html, css

**HTML code:**

```
<div class='abc'>
    <a>test1</a>
    <a class='active'>test2</a>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```css
.abc a { color: red; }
.active { color: green; }
```

Result: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4n642ett/)

**Question**:

As you can see, all tag A appear red color, class '.active' doesn't take effect, what caused this result and how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Read up on CSS specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity & http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: This is because `.abc a` selector is more specific than `.active`. If you change the second CSS selector to either `.abc .active` or `a.active` it will work.

Answer (score 10):

`.abc a` consists of a class selector and a type selector.

`.active` consists of only a class selector.

This means `.abc a` is more [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity). Since they both match the same element and set the same property, the more specific one wins.

Make the rule you want to apply more specific: `.abc a.active`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
.abc a{color: red}
.abc .active{color:green}
```

The reason it's not working is because your first line of CSS is more specific than just .active and will always take priority. The more specific the more priority will have.

Answer (score 0):

".abc a" takes precedence over ".active"
What you are looking for is:
.abc .active

Answer (score 0):

you will need to this

**Js fiddle**

```
  .abc a{color: red}

  a.active{color:green}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.abc a{color: red}
a.active{color:green}
```

To override a property...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of specifity (like the other answers pointed out). Another way to force this would be to add !important at the end of the style:

```
.active { color: green !important; }
```

Not the most elegant solution (actually discouraged), but may work in scenarios where coding all of the specifity scenarios would involve too much work (e.g. changing the color of all elements with class active in response to an alert). More information: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm

Comment: I don't see why the downvote, this is another alternative and shouldn't be downvoted. I clearly stated this is used to "force" the style. If you downvote, at least comment why you did it.

Comment: maybe they don't recommend your answer.

Comment: but I don't see a comment as of why "they" don't recommend it

Comment: yeah some, people just like to down vote your answer. just because they can. I know how it feels.

Comment: I'm guessing the reason for the down vote (it wasn't me) is  that the use of `!important` is generally discouraged. However this may be one of those instances where it is valid. If you want everything on the site with an active class to have a color of green you don't want to be coding around the various specificity scenarios. When using `!important` you should know why you have to use it and wether it can be avoided by using specificity.

Comment: That is correct, it is discouraged (that's why it is not elegant) but it may still be valid in cases like the one you've just described.

Comment: Then you should mention that it is discouraged in your answer, and why it may be a valid solution in this case.